# How can I share my bokeh app with others?

Tags: python, server, bokeh

if i write a bokeh server app like one in the gallary
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html#id2

can somebody else open this on their computer?

thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is the issue?

Comment: When I want to see this server app, i can use the cmd "bokeh serve --show app.py" to see the figure.
However, if i want to show other people in a different country, how should they see this figure on their computer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a public static IP address that's routed to the host where `bokeh serve` is running.

And when you run `bokeh serve`, add `--address` argument with the an IP address that's routed to (or is the same as) that public IP address. Or with just `0.0.0.0` to make it listen on all IP addresses that the host has.